# DirectShow stream using ffmpeg point to point streaming through TCP protocol

Tags: tcp, ffmpeg, udp, point-to-point

I had set up a point-to-point stream using ffmpeg via UDP protocol and the stream worked, but there was screen tearing etc. I already tried raising the buffer size, but it did not help. This is a work network, so the UDP protocol won't work.
here is the full command:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow  -i video="UScreenCapture"  -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts udp://192.168.1.220:1234?pkt_size=188?buffer_size=65535
```

I've tried to make this work with TCP with no success
Here's what i've got now:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -f mpegts tcp://192.168.1.194:5555
```

this returns an error:

> real-time buffer [UScreenCapture] [Video input] too full or near too
>   full <323% of size: 3041280 [rtbufsize parameter]>! frame dropped!

This last message repeated xxxx times (it went up to around 1400 and I just turned it off).

I've tried to implement the `-rtbufsize` paremeter and raising the buffsize up to 800000000, didn't help.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: How do i set up a point to point stream using TCP using ffmpeg?

Comment: By using this command line:

ffmpeg -rtbufsize 2048M -f dshow  -i video="UScreenCapture"  -r 30 -vcodec mpeg4 -q 12 -f mpegts tcp://192.168.1.194:5555

the command prompt returns: tcp://192.168.1.194:5555: unknown error